# Why does my Flutter app drop down to the bottom of the screen on exit?

Tags: android, flutter

I've done a custom launch screen, but I don't know how I've changed the way the app fades out? It drops to the bottom of a device. The only thing I did was swap to translucent theme in AndroidManifest.xml

https://media.giphy.com/media/KDh7K2bLVLQNsj93ob/giphy.gif

I've compared a brand new Flutter app with the same SDK and the only difference I can see is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when Flutter draws its first frame -->
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

vs

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when Flutter draws its first frame -->
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's it. Switching a fresh Flutter app to `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` in styles.xml reproduces the dropout. I just want rid of the Black bar!

Thanks for being my [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/).